# how to restore a sql server backup whose file is on another machine?

Tags: sql-server, restore

How is it possible to restore a database in Machine A (where sql server is installed) from the backup file located in Machine B.

Is it possible to avoid to copy the bak file to the machine A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes it is](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1126).

Answer (score 1):

Create a file share on machine B. Then restore from the file there.

Although you don't create a copy of the file 'per se' you still have to get the content of the backup file across.

Answer (score 1):

You have to (read: want to) get that file on the server hosting SQL Server.  Assuming that this is a large file, you don't want to restore from across the network which will be much slower.  If you can't copy it because of the time involved, or the space on the SQL Server, I'd suggest an external USB drive or something.